# Clustering of locators on three different nodes in apache geode

Tags: cluster-analysis, geode

I want to clustering a locator in three different nodes or boxes in Apache Geode and if its possible, is there any way we can make Master slave feature or HA feature. Client can connect to any locator which is less occupied at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Geode locators are already highly available. Clients will automatically retry to another locator if one is not available, without impacting your application.

Clients will automatically discover new locators. So it's technically possible to start all of your client point only at a single locator and let it discover the rest. However it's better practice to pass in the list of known locators when starting your client in case one locator is not available at startup.